# Product attribute in iframe

Tags: magento-1.9, php, html

I have an iframe on the product page that holds a personlisation tool. I want to use a yes/no product attribute in the frame to show or hide a tab. I've tried the following but get error Call to a member function getData() on a non-object

```
<?php if($_product->getData('has_photo')==1){?>
<li class="active" role="presentation"><a aria-expanded="true"   
aria-controls="clipartTab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" id="photo-btn" 
href="#clipartTab"><span class="pdc-image"></span><?php echo 
$this->__('Graphics'); ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the top of the file:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

and then changed the code to this:

```
<?php if($product->getData('has_photo')==1){?>
<li class="active" role="presentation"><a aria-expanded="true"   
aria-controls="clipartTab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" id="photo-btn" 
href="#clipartTab"><span class="pdc-image"></span><?php echo 
$this->__('Graphics'); ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```